# CSS - creating a div with content that is a set height

Tags: css

I was wondering if there is a way with CSS to set the height of a div and to have that height stay the same even if content goes inside that div ... instead of pushing it down it stays the same.

For example, i want to use jquery slidedown and slide up functions, but i dont want the rest of the content to slide, so if i put a div with a set height just outside the content i want to slide, then the height will stay the same.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `height` attribute to specify the height of the div, and you can prevent content from expanding outside of it by setting `overflow:hidden;`

Code:

```
#wrapper {
    height: 20px;
    background-color: orange;
    overflow:hidden;
}

<div id="wrapper">
    content<br/>
    content<br/>
    content<br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the `max-height` property, although that's not supported in IE6 (like that matters anymore).

Comment: Yeh, im not worried about ie6 ... if i had that and i put a <p> tag inside the div, would it push the other content down?